# Regular distribution function

Tags: distribution-theory

For a regular distribution F we know it can be identified by a locally integrable function s.t
$$F(\phi) =  \int_{ℝ^N}f(x)\phi(x)dx \space,\space x \in ℝ^N \space,\space \phi(x) \in D(ℝ^N) $$
I've assumed the function f is unique for a given distribution but I can't find anything to confirm or explain why this is, I know this is kind of a simple question but I'm not getting any help from my book or google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ will be unique up to sets of measure zero.  Remember, $f$ really isn't a function but rather an equivalence class of functions who are equal a.e. i.e. a member of $L^1_{loc}$. So if we define the distribution as the integration of a smooth function of compact support again a member of $L^1_{loc}$ then the uniqueness is really a result of integration.   Try working it out, suppose you have two different $f_1,f_2 \in L^1_{loc}$ what can you say about the distributions they define in the above manner?

Comment: Do you mean if we have two different $$f_1,f_2 \in L^1_{loc}$$ who both define the same regular distribution, what that would mean? In that case can I just show that $$ (f_1 - f_2)$$ must equal zero?

Comment: yes, if $f_1 and f_2$ are distinct then there is a compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $\|(f_1-f_2)\chi_K\|_1=0$ Then what can we say about the distributions they define?

Comment: correction: $\|(f_1-f_2)\chi_K\|_1>0$

Comment: So if the norm is 0 for all test functions over K then the functions must be equal over K and then the distributions are the same? (I'm not sure what you mean by $$ \chi_K$$ but I assume you mean test function?) So if I'm understanding correctly you mean proof would look something like $$\int_{ℝ^N}f_1 \phi dx = \int_{ℝ^N}f_2 \phi dx \Rightarrow \int_{ℝ^N}(f_1-f_2) \phi dx = 0 \Rightarrow \|(f_1-f_2) \phi \|_1=0 \Rightarrow f_1 = f_2 $$

Comment: $\chi_K$ is the characteristic function on $K$

Comment: yes your argument looks good, the last two implications need a little more. Remember $L^1$ norm is defined by the integral of the absolute value. and the last implication is a result of Holder's inequality